# How to determine if a number is prime

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, primes

Okay my issue is less of how to figure out if a number is prime, because I think I figured that out, but more of how to get it to display properly.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare Variables
    int randomNumbers = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    //Loop for number generation and print out numbers
    System.out.print("The five random numbers are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        randomNumbers = (int)(Math.random()*20);
        sum += randomNumbers;

        if (i == 4) {
            System.out.println("and " + randomNumbers + ".");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(randomNumbers + ", ");
        }
    }
    //Display Sum
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of these five numbers is " + sum + ".\n");

    //Determine if the sum is prime and display results
    for(int p = 2; p < sum; p++) {
        if(sum % p == 0)
            System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number.");
        else 
            System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
        break;
        }
    }


}
```

Now my problem is, if the number ends up being something like 9, it'll say it is a prime number, which it is not. I think the issue is that the break is stopping it after one loop so it's not incrementing variable p so it's only testing dividing by 2 (I think). But if I remove the break point it will print out "The sum is/is not a prime number" on every pass until it exits the loop. Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method for finding if your number is prime is the correct method.
To make it so that it does not consistently print out whether or not the number is prime, you could have an external variable, which represents whether or not the number is prime.

Such as

```
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int p = 2; p < sum; p++) {
        if (sum % p == 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (prime)
        System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
    else
        System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number.");
```

By doing this method the program will assume the number is prime until it proves that wrong. So when it finds it is not prime it sets the variable to false and breaks out of the loop.

Then after the loop finishes you just have to print whether or not the number was prime.

A way that you could make this loop faster is to go from when p = 2 to when p = the square root of sum. So using this method your for loop will look like this:

```
    double sq = Math.sqrt((double)sum);
    for (int p = 2; p < sq; p++) {
        //Rest of code goes here
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Very helpful, although you left the break; in there and that was messing me up until I realized I needed to get rid of it. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: The break is there to exit the loop the first time it finds a factor, since it doesn't need to look for any more.

Comment: Your logic is correct but it's not optimized. So iterate the `for` loop only upto square root of number rather than upto number. And increment the  `for` loop variable(starting with 3) by 2 rather than 1. I have posted a answer, please refer to that for more details.

Comment: The last for-loop should include upper range edge, like this
for (int p = 2; p < sq; p++)

otherwise it will return incorrect results, stating that 4 and 9 are prime numbers

Comment: 1 is not prime.  
An integer greater than one is called a prime number if its only positive divisors (factors) are one and itself.

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop include the square root: `p <= sq`? If we're testing e.g. the number 9 the above code would not test for `9 % 3` since the loop would exit after the first execution of the body of the loop. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

You need to store whether or not the number is prime in a boolean outside of the loop:

```
//Determine if the sum is prime and display results
boolean isPrime = true;
for(int p = 2; p < sum; p++) {
    if(sum % p == 0){
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(isPrime){
   System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
} else {
   System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number."); 
}
```

Comment: Your logic is correct but it's not optimized. So iterate the for loop only upto square root of number rather than upto number. And increment the for loop variable(starting with 3) by 2 rather than 1. I have posted a answer, please refer to that for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, currently your code tests dividing by two, and the break command is stopping after one loop.

After the first go of your loop (p==2), the `break` will always stop the loop.

The fastest fix to your code will change the loop part like this:

```
boolean isPrime=true;
for(int p = 2; p < sum; p++) {
    if(sum % p == 0) {
        isPrime=false;
        System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number.");
        break;
    }
}
if (isPrime)
    System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
```

This code can be improved for efficiency and for code elegance.

For efficiency, you don't need to check divisibility by all numbers smaller than sum, it's enough to check all numbers smaller by square-root of sum.

For better code, create a seperate function to test if a number is prime.

Here is an example that implements both.

```
 // tests if n is prime
 public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
     if (n<2) return false;
     for(int p = 2; p < Math.sqrt(n); p++) {
        if(n % p == 0) return false;  // enough to find one devisor to show n is not a prime
     }
     return true; // no factors smaller than sqrt(n) were found
 }

 public static void main(String []args){
    ...
    System.out.println("sum is "+ sum);
    if (isPrime(sum)) 
        System.out.println("The sum is a prime number.");
    else 
        System.out.println("The sum is not a prime number.");
 }
```

Comment: You have mentioned `Math.sqrt(n)` inside for loop parenthesis which is bad pratice. It's degrading performance by calculating square root again and again. It's better to store square root of number in temporary variable and use inside for loop.

Comment: Increment the for loop variable(starting with 3) by 2 rather than 1. I have posted a answer, please refer to that for more details.

Answer (score 2):

## Small prime numbers

Use [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi) **primality test**, method is related to prime numbers in the range of `int`. You can find source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/primes/Primes.java).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>

// org.apache.commons.math3.primes.Primes
Primes.isPrime(2147483629);
```

> It uses the Miller-Rabin probabilistic test in such a way that a
> result is guaranteed: it uses the firsts prime numbers as successive
> base (see Handbook of applied cryptography by [Menezes, table 4.1](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf) / page 140).

## Big prime numbers

If you are looking for primes larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

1. Use [`BigInteger#isProbablePrime(int certainty)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime-int-) to pre-verify the prime candidate

   > Returns true if this BigInteger is probably prime, false if it's
   > definitely composite. If certainty is ≤ 0, true is returned.
   > Parameters: certainty - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller
   > is willing to tolerate: if the call returns true the probability that
   > this BigInteger is prime exceeds (1 - 1/2certainty). The execution
   > time of this method is proportional to the value of this parameter.
2. Next use ["AKS Primality Test"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aks-primality-test/) to check whether the candidate is indeed prime.

Answer (score 1):

So many answers have been posted so far which are correct but none of them is optimized. That's why I thought to share the optimized code to determine prime number here with you. Please have a look at below code snippet...

```
private static boolean isPrime(int iNum) {
boolean bResult = true;
if (iNum <= 1 || iNum != 2 && iNum % 2 == 0) {
    bResult = false;
} else {
    int iSqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(iNum);
    for (int i = 3; i < iSqrt; i += 2) {
    if (iNum % i == 0) {
        bResult = false;
        break;
    }
    }
}
return bResult;
}
```

> Benefits of above code-:

1. It'll work for negative numbers and 0 & 1 as well.
2. It'll run the `for` loop only for odd numbers.
3. It'll increment the `for` loop variable by 2 rather than 1.
4. It'll iterate the `for` loop only upto square root of number rather than upto number.

> Explanation-:

I have mentioned the four points above which I'll explain one by one. Code must be appropriately written for the **invalid inputs rather the only for valid input**. Whatever answers have been written so far are restricted to valid range of input in which number `iNum >=2`.

We should be aware that **only odd numbers can be prime**, ***Note-: 2 is the only one even prime.*** So we must not run `for` loop for even numbers.

We must not run `for` loop for even values of it's variable `i` as we know that only even numbers can be devided by even number. I have already mentioned in the above point that only odd numbers can be prime except 2 as even. **So no need to run code inside `for` loop for even values of variable `i` in `for`**.

We should iterate `for` loop only upto **square root** of number rather than upto number. Few of the answers has implemented this point but still I thought to mention it here.

Answer (score 1):

With most efficient time Complexity ie O(sqrt(n)) :

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {

    for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Java BigInteger class' isProbablePrime method to determine and print whether the sum is prime or not prime in an easy way.

```
 BigInteger number = new BigInteger(sum);
        if(number.isProbablePrime(1)){
            System.out.println("prime");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not prime");
        }
```

You can read more about this method here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29