# Determine if a number is prime

Tags: java

```
public static void isPrime(int number)
{
    for ( int i = 2; i<number ; i ++)
    {
      if ( number%i!=0 ) {
        System.out.println(number + " is not a prime ");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println(number +" is  a prime ");
      }
    }
```

and the results is :

> 60 is  a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is  a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is  a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime
>   60 is not a prime

All I want is whether it's a prime or not; in this case it isn't.

Comment: Indent your code properly and you should see problem better.

Comment: You're just performing one check per number and immediately saying a number is a prime if you can divide it by `i` (instead of checking all of the other `i` as well)

Comment: Also try to explain your algorithm. What makes you think it should give different results then what you are getting now?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: All of the other issues in your code aside, it's not necessary to have your `for` loop run from 2 to `n`. You can stop at `sqrt(n)`. In every pair of factors of `n`, one of them will be less than or equal to `sqrt(n)`. Have a look at this [proof](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176/803925).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a number is prime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199440/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-prime)

Comment: Only print the result once you know the final outcome, don't print it every time inside the loop. BTW you only need to check 2 and odd numbers up to the square root of the number tested.

Comment: yall are merciless. crushing the poor soul with at least 13 downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a bracket. If you keep your code clean it will solve the problem.

Also in your if statement you are checking if `number % 2 != 0`. If it does not equal to 0 then it could potentially be a prime number. So I changed it to `number % 2 == 0` to fix the problem.

The other mistake is that you kept printing even after you knew that the number is not prime.

```
public static void isPrime(int number)
    {
        for ( int i = 2; i<Math.sqrt(number) + 1; i ++)
        {
            if ( number%i==0 ) {//If number is not a prime
                //Will print that the number is not a prime once
                System.out.println(number +" is not a prime number.");
                return ; //Will exit the method
            }
        }
        //If you reach this point then the number is prime.
        System.out.println(number +" is a prime number.");
    }
```

Comment: You're probably going to want `i < Math.sqrt(number) + 1`, since it needs to be less than or equal to the square-root, and `Math.sqrt` returns a double (not every number is a perfect square).

Comment: Make sure to select best answer

Comment: but why use the sqrt i just want to understand

Comment: Look at the 4th comment to your question made by @nbrooks

Comment: @YahiaA.Seridi select this answer as the answer to your question so that it registers as answered.